# How to determine the area under the curve using matlab?

Tags: matlab, area

if i have x data

```
x = [a, b, c, d ...]
```

and y data

```
y= [a, b, c, d...]
```

and assumes that this is the plot of that x and y

[image]

How can i get or determine the area under the curve? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You just might try out trapz(x,y).

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/154089-area-under-curve-no-function

Comment: Will `trapz` give the correct answer given that `x` is not strictly increasing?

Comment: is it applicable for this kind of non-linear graph? thanks

Comment: To answer my own question, a quick test indicates that it does work for your non-linear graph. Try `x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]; y = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]; plot(x, y); trapz(x, y)` then `x = [1 2 3 4 3 6 7]; y = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]; plot(x, y); trapz(x, y)`. You can easily calculate the difference in area from the graph and verify that it works correctly.

Comment: An edit showing how to use `trapz` would be more fruitful.  Simply pointing to documentation isn't useful.